# Bitrise Firebase App Distribution Error: failed to upload release. HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission

Tags: firebase, apk, bitrise, firebase-app-distribution

I am getting the below error while uploading the APK on firebase app distribution via Bitrise.

```
Error: Failed to upload release. HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I forgot to add bitrise email in the firebase project under users & Permission as an owner. Then you need to accept the invitation by logging in to the email which you have added.

```
Steps : 

- Login to firebase project
- Go to Project Setting
- User & Permissions
- Add User with owner access (Add the email id which used in the bitrise)
- You will receive the invite to the added email id.
- Login to the email & Accept the invitation.
```